# ActiveRecord: How to get all attributes of a model that can be mass-assigned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to have a list of all attribute names that can be mass assigned. I need this for a custom form builder that will not add input fields by default that cannot be mass assigned.

For example if I have the following model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :account

  belongs_to :author

  validates_presence_of :title, :author
end
```

I would like to have as a result `[:author, :title]`.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Post.accessible_attributes would cover it if you explicitly defined attr_accessible

Barring, that, doing something like this is clunky but works:

```
Post.new.attributes.keys - Post.protected_attributes.to_a
```

Comment: so, if accessible_attributes gets the ones that are explicitly attr_accessible'd and protected_attributes gets the ones that are explicitly attr_protect'd, is there a method that will tell you which ones are accessible regardless of whether they are protected through attr_protected or attr_accessible ?

Comment: Thank you for posting. This was a great addition to my filter attributes method.

Comment: There's a problem, this will list :created_at, :updated_at as accessible attributes !!, they're not

Comment: @MhdSyrwan: are you sure you aren't saying that :created_at and :updated_at `SHOULDN'T` be accessible instead of `ARE NOT`? if you pass an input with name="post[created_at]" and value="01/01/2012" won't it go to the model? here it does. Depends on your Rails version(Rails core will change the defaults after the Github/accessible attributes scandal).

Comment: @BrenoSalgado: you're right :) , it depends on rails version

http://chrisroos.co.uk/blog/2009-04-19-rails-2-3-and-the-ability-to-update-created_at-created_on-updated_at-and-updated_on-timestamps

Answer (score 89):

Some of the previously mentioned answers may not apply for Rails 4.

You can use `MyModel.attribute_names` to get the array of table attributes, although, that might not give you mass assignable attributes, as this aspect of Rails changes with version 4 http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/

Comment: this is what I needed thanks. I'm hacking around disabling mass assignment for just a model. :-)

Answer (score 28):

For Models you can use `MyModel.attribute_names` or `MyModel.column_names`.

For instances you can use `MyModel.new.attribute_names`.

Answer (score 25):

Just use

```
Post.accessible_attributes
```

That will return all the [attributes accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Generators/ModelGenerator/accessible_attributes) of the class

Comment: Note that if using multiple roles, you can get your different lists by passing the symbol - `Post.accessible_attributes(:user)`, `Post.accessible_attributes(:admin)`, etc. I've also found `Post.active_authorizers` helpful, it returns a hash of all defined roles and their accessible attributes.

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Using Ruby 2.2.2; Rails 4.1.2: I have a `User` model backed by a database table. For `User.accessible_attributes`, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method "accessible_attributes" for #<Class:0x007f9216346fe8>`

Comment: My rails version 4.2.6 but it return error. But @Scudelletti 's answer works.

Answer (score 3):

`Post.accessible_attributes.to_a.map(&:to_sym)`

Comment: A little explanation would be better.

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.