# mass updating attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I am using Sinatra but I am guessing this also applies to Rails (if not, please remove the tag or let me know and I will remove it).

I have a ActiveRecord::Base class `User`. It has tons of attributes and I am displaying a page that will allow someone to update the a particular user. Problem is, I have a hard time implementing the update functionality in a DRY manner. What I mean is, when I get the `params` with a POST request, I can do:

```
a_user.update_attributes params
```

because params contains bnch of other crap too (like `:splat` - what's that?) and it will throw an unknown attribute error. What I instead have to do is this:

```
a_user.update_attributes {:attrA => params[:attrA], 
                          :attrB => params[:attrB], ...etc }
```

*(keep in mind there are A LOT of attributes)*

Is this how I should do this? To me, for some reason...it doesn't feel right. If for example, I have another Model that needs to be updated in a similar manner, I have to rewrite manually all attributes again.

What I am looking for is somethign like:

```
a_user.filter_and_update_attributes params
```

where filter_and_update_attributes automatically filters params of any bad/unknown attributes and I can use this anywhere with any models with have to rewrite so much useless code.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you structure your form like this:

```
<form action="/users" method="post">
  <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="text">
  <input id="user_name" name="user[name]" type="text">
  <input id="user_phone_number" name="user[phone_number]" type="text">
  ...
  <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="text">
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

you should be able to use the params like this:

```
@user.update_attributes params[:user]
```

When you name your html fields like `user[email]`, the params hash looks like:

```
{ user: { email: "example@example.com", name: "Example" } }
```

So using `params[:user]` gets you that nested hash of parameters that belong to the user.

Answer (score -1):

You can filter a hash using [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select). Find a list of [all attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1526066/520779) of your model and test if the keys are in that list:

```
attrs = a_user.attributes.keys - User.protected_attributes.to_a
a_user.update_attributes params.select {|k,v| attrs.include?(k)}
```

Comment: @downvoter could you please comment on what is wrong with my answer, so I can learn from my mistakes?

Comment: not the downvoter, but it looks like a perfectly valid answer to me (if you change `select(...)` to `select{...}`) :)