# Rails nested attributes form for polymorphic/single table inheritance associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, nested-attributes

I am working on a form (using SimpleForm) that allows you to edit embedded associations. The problem that I'm running into is that the nested models are subclasses so they are different types with potentially different fields. I'm creating hidden forms for each type of model, and using JavaScript to display the form for the selected type.

FYI, I'm using the following gems:

- Rails 3.2
- Mongoid
- SimpleForm

Here's a simplified example of what I have so far:

```
class Garage
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :vehicle
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicle
end

class Vehicle
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :garage
  attr_accessible :_type
end

class Car < Vehicle
  field :car_field
  attr_accessible :car_field
end

class Truck < Vehicle
  field :truck_field
  attr_accessible :truck_field
end
```

In the console:

```
> garage = Garage.new
> garage.vehicle = Car.new(car_field: 'something')
> garage.save!
```

In the form:

```
= simple_form_for @garage do |f|
  = f.input :vehicle do |vehicle_form|
     = vehicle_form.input :_type, collection: ['Car', 'Truck']

  %span.hide{data:{fields-for:'Car'}}
    = vehicle_form.input :car_field

  %span.hide{data:{fields-for:'Truck'}}
    = vehicle_form.input :truck_field

:coffeescript
  $('#garage_vehicle_attributes__type').change ->
    type = $(@).find('option:selected').val()
    $('[data-fields-for="' + type + '"]').show()
```

The problem that will occur in this example is that it won't be able to render the `truck_field` because `Car` does not have a `truck_field` method. I'm not sure how to solve this problem besides throwing out any form helpers and managing the html and field values manually. Even after much Googling, I haven't been able to find any examples of this type of form.

How can this problem be solved in a standard, "Rails way" using existing form helpers?

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327236/polymorphism-and-forms-in-ruby-on-rails (but not sure)

Comment: @jethroo thanks, but unfortunately the answer covers everything I already have in my code sample. They leave off the last step of working with different fields for different models.

Comment: If the base document haven't got any common fields, I would think on the lines of creating two sets of fields, one for truck(with a new blank instance) and one for car, setting `_destroy` on vehicle type switch and creating a new truck document. If that doesn't work for you or seems too inelegant, other option is to move all fields to base document, because if you convert car to a truck, I believe mongoid will not unset car_field and your document in db will have more fields than it needs. Right way to switch document type is to assign new document and not edit existing in place IMHO.

Comment: @rubish Good tip, I discovered that as well. I have an `embeds_many` association too, so the solution for that is a little different.

Comment: I think embeds_many is relatively easy to handle than embeds one, as you can destroy old documents and create new ones in a single call using existing mechanisms of nested attributes. However, with embeds_one, you will need to create new document and override existing one and also make sure that if there is any cleanup to be done on destroying the document(like deleting s3 files), its taken care of properly.

Comment: stupid question : if you already know your vehicle type, why would you want to select it in the form ? Shouldn't you have @garage.vehicle = Vehicle.new & then tell Vehicle what type it'll end up being ?

Comment: @charlysisto Yes, you select what type of vehicle, and by selecting the type of vehicle you are given additional fields specific to the type you have selected.

Comment: what about rendering you form based on the accessible attributes? like: attr_accessible = vehicle.attributes.keys - vehicle.protected_attributes.to_a *, this will ensure you will only build valid forms for your vehicle type and this could be done in a dynamic way, given there are not to complex fields so the formhelper can render the input forms by himself without telling him what to do (no custom dropdowns i.e.)  *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526066/how-to-get-the-list-of-attributes-of-a-activerecord-model-that-can-be-mass-assig

Comment: @jethroo Interesting idea, but I don't think that will work. I'd like to see a code sample for how to build the form that way. Right now I'm using partials for the fields of the different classes which also provides a way to customize the form markup if I need to.

Answer (score 2):

I think I had a similar problem, however instead of a `has_one` relationship, I have `has_many`.

Basically I used `cocoon` gem to dynamically add fields for each decorated class (such as `Car` or `Truck`) and then I `accept_nested_attributes_for :vehicle`. The form is built dynamically and on submit, the parameters go inside `vehicle_attributes`.

The code looks something like (updated for `has_one` association):

```
# _form.html.haml

= simple_form_for @garage, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|

  = f.simple_fields_for :vehicles do |vehicle|
    = render 'vehicle_fields', :f => item
    = link_to_add_association 'Add a Car', f, :vehicles, :wrap_object => Proc.new { |vehicle| vehicle = Car.new }
    = link_to_add_association 'Add a Truck', f, :vehicles, :wrap_object => Proc.new { |vehicle| vehicle = Truck.new }

= f.button :submit, :disable_with => 'Please wait ...', :class => "btn btn-primary", :value => 'Save'
```

Then inside `_vehicle_fields` partial you check what object it is (`Car` or `Truck`) and you render the correct fields.

I think this works quite good, and was exactly what I needed. Hope it helps.

I wrote a longer explanation at: http://www.powpark.com/blog/programming/2014/05/07/rails_nested_forms_for_single_table_inheritance_associations

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those situations where directly mapping a form to a model is not ideal. I think a user-filled form map and a persistence model instance are two very distinct concepts.

You might try subclassing Vehicle into a class that is used to accept form data. Then mix in all the extra code you need to handle what is specific to the form. This way, you keep your `Vehicle` model clean. You can also override methods in `VehicleFormModel` to work like a factory, to build the correct instance when the object is being created. In your controller, instantiate a VehicleFormModel instead of a Vehicle.

```
class VehicleFormModel < Vehicle
  include Car::FormModel
  include Truck::FormModel

  def self.build
    # Use a form field to handle specifics for each type,
    # delegating to the mixed in FormModel as needed
  end

end

class Car < Vehicle
  module FormModel
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        field :car_field
        attr_accessible :car_field
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I see there's a Railscast that might cover this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects

Comment: Interesting idea. I would like to see more of the HTML/JavaScript implementation for this though.

Comment: I watched the RailsCast again, it's pretty comprehensive.

Comment: I've already seen the screencast. I was referring to the specifics of this type of form that creates different fields based on a previous field you select.