# nested form two blocks for the same association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-form-for

I'm using [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) with a legacy app and I have a polymorphic association. I'm wanting to be able to render two different blocks depending on the button clicked. Right now, regardless of the `link_to_add` that I click, it's always rendering the second `field_for` block.

foo.rb:

```
class Foo
  belongs_to :task, polymorphic: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for: :task
end
```

foo/edit.html.erb:

```
<%= f.fields_for :task do |task_form| %>
  <%= task_form.hidden_field :type, value: 'Some::Type' %>
<% end %>
<%= task_form.link_to_add "add some task", :task %>

<%= f.fields_for :task do |task_form| %>
  <%= task_form.hidden_field :type, value: 'Some::OtherType' %>
<% end %>
<%= task_form.link_to_add "add some other task", :task %>
```

How can I get it to add the separate blocks, depending on which button I press?

Comment: I'm confused. `belongs_to` implies that there is a single `task_id` field in the `Foo` table that points to one row in the `Task` table. Using a nested form to add an additional record seems contrary to the singular nature of `belongs_to`.

Comment: But it's a polymorphic association, so it has a `task_id` and a `task_type` and could refer to any model.

Comment: Yes, it could refer to multiple models, but there will only ever be *one* of them at a time, right? If that's the case, you don't want to ever link_to_add because you might end up submitting two of something.

Comment: Maybe you want to try the Cocoon gem? I've had success, and the answer here looks like it has some possibility... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412409/rails-nested-attributes-form-for-polymorphic-single-table-inheritance-associatio